# What access modifier for testable helper methods?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, package, access-modifiers, kotlin

In Java, helper methods are often marked `protected` instead of `private`, so that unit tests within the same package can test the helper methods. (Specifically, I am using JUnit.)

This does not seem to work in Kotlin. What access modifier is recommended instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`internal` (or no modifier) works well here